# How to set multiple applications as device owners/administrators in Android

Tags: android, android-security

In a new device (no accounts yet), I can make an application as a device owner and admin using this command.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner me.mypackagename/.AdminReceiver
```

How to make multiple apps as device administrators/owners (pre-set without user permission) so that user can not remove them from device and they have all control over device policies.

Answer (score 0):

Only one application can be made as device owner.

However multiple apps can be given device administrator permissions.

Also you can set uninstall blocked for the other apps using the device owner app by using this command

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(context, AdminReceiver.class);
dpm.setUninstallBlocked(mDeviceAdmin, packagename, allow);
```